# issue with Runtime Permission

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-permissions

I don't know why but my code for runtime permission doesn't work. Not appear pop up. Progress bar appear without that I accept permission.

Who can help me?

THANKS IN ADVANCE EVERYBODY!

I show you my code:!

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the custom_spinner_items for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_four, container, false);



        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cazzo);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (hasPermissions()) {
                    // our app has permissions.
                    FiveFragment ff = new FiveFragment();
                    numeroTavolo = ff.showResultTavolo(v);

                    MyListFragment mlf = new MyListFragment();


               /* try {
                    mlf.showResultTotale(v);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                    string2 = mlf.showResultTotale2(v);
                    totalepizze = mlf.showResultTotale(v);


                    ThreeFragment tf = new ThreeFragment();

                    string4 = tf.showResult(v);

                    totalebibite = tf.showResult2(v);
                    processingDialog.show();
                    mProgressbarAsync = new MakePDF();
                    mProgressbarAsync.execute();
                    new MakePDF(getContext()).execute();

                } else {
                    //our app doesn't have permissions, So i m requesting permissions.
                    requestPerms();
                }

               /* FiveFragment ff = new FiveFragment();
                numeroTavolo = ff.showResultTavolo(v);

                MyListFragment mlf = new MyListFragment();


               *//* try {
                    mlf.showResultTotale(v);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*//*

                string2 = mlf.showResultTotale2(v);
                totalepizze = mlf.showResultTotale(v);


                ThreeFragment tf = new ThreeFragment();

                    string4 = tf.showResult(v);

                    totalebibite = tf.showResult2(v);
             */
               /* string4=tf.showResult(v);
                totalebibite=tf.showResult2(v);*/

                   /* processingDialog.show();
                    mProgressbarAsync = new MakePDF();
                    mProgressbarAsync.execute();
                    new MakePDF(getContext()).execute();*/


            }

        });
        TextView titolo2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
        return rootView;
    }
```

CODE ABOUT PERMISSION:

```
 private void requestPerms(){
            String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                requestPermissions(permissions,PERMS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

        private boolean hasPermissions(){

            int res = 0;
            //string array of permissions,
            String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            for (String perms : permissions){
                res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(getContext(),perms);
                if (!(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                    return false;

                }
            }
            return true;

        }






        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            boolean allowed = true;

            switch (requestCode){
                case PERMS_REQUEST_CODE:

                    for (int res : grantResults){
                        // if user granted all permissions.
                        allowed = allowed && (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    // if user not granted permissions.
                    allowed = false;
                    break;

            }

            if (allowed){
                //user granted all permissions we can perform our task.
                //makeFolder();
                FiveFragment ff = new FiveFragment();
                numeroTavolo = ff.showResultTavolo(v);

                MyListFragment mlf = new MyListFragment();


                   /* try {
                        mlf.showResultTotale(v);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/

                string2 = mlf.showResultTotale2(v);
                totalepizze = mlf.showResultTotale(v);


                ThreeFragment tf = new ThreeFragment();

                string4 = tf.showResult(v);

                totalebibite = tf.showResult2(v);
                processingDialog.show();
                 mProgressbarAsync = new MakePDF();
                mProgressbarAsync.execute();
                new MakePDF(getContext()).execute();
            }
            else {
                // we will give warning to user that they haven't granted permissions.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Storage Permissions denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is your target sdk? What is the api level of your device or virtual device you're testing on?

Comment: If you want an easy and working code you can add the one class from
https://github.com/mptrista/PermissionHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your tarketSdkVersion?

Runtime Permission need (23 >= tarketSdkVerison)

And check your app,

move "phone > setting > application > your app > permission"

you deny your permission. then you run your app

Comment: my app: minSdkVersion 15,        targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: What is your android os version? Before you build your app(runtime permission), your phone was having your app. After delete your app, and build your app.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this it works my side.

1. I am using for Contact permission in Fragment

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           runReadContact();
       } else {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MyActivity.PERMISSION_CODE);
       }
   } else {
       runReadContact();
   }
   ```
2. `onRequestPermission()` use in MyActivity (Activity Class) like this

   ```
   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case MyActivity.PERMISSION_CODE:
       if (grantResults.length > 0)
           if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   runReadContact();

           }
       }
       break;
     }
   }
   ```
3. if you want to use onRequestPermission() within fragment
   we need to take care about.

   1) android.support.v4.app.Fragment; => import android.app.Fragment

   2) FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(...

   3) You use this "onRequestPermissionsResult(..." within fragment it works.

Comment: i stay in fragment not in activity

Comment: use => ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMS_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: i extend fragment not activity

Comment: I am using this => 1)if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                runReadContact();
            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 101);
            }
        } else {
            runReadContact();
        }       in Fragment

Comment: and in fragment request result code also working in same fragment =>  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0)
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (requestCode == 101) {
                    runReadContact();
                }
            }
    }

Comment: can you update your answer please? so i can see better

Comment: Updated my Answer and its working from my side may be it helps at your side :)

Comment: my code does' t work....not appear pop up about permission.....can you write how i must write my code?please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Debug your application check if hasPermissions() function returns
   true or false it is true then your application already has a
   permission it won't show a popup.
2. Check your Manifest.xml file. if it has permission defined and you are running below API level 23 still it won't show popup.
3. Run your application on device having API level 23 (marshmallow) and above.

Hope this solves your problem.